# Unexpectedly found nil while trying to unwrap UIImage

Tags: swift

For some reason when I try to initialize an image I get nil. 
The image is saved in Assets folder and the name is correct. What would it cause it to be nil?

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == Storyboard.groupDetailsVC {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? GroupDetailsViewController {

            vc.groupImageView.image =  UIImage(named: "icon-checkbox")
            //it outputs error 

        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to pass image to GroupDetailsViewController just pass the image not. Not try to set image in prepareSegu.

Comment: Set the image into the GroupDetailsViewController viewDidLoad, not in the prepareForSegue

Comment: Problem is that your groupImageView outlet is still not connected because CV's loadview did not called at this point. you must create a variable of UIImage in your VC and can assign this to the image you are creating.

Comment: I understand. I should have realized that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the image it's in accessing imageView before the Vc loads

```
vc.groupImageView.image =  UIImage(named: "icon-checkbox")
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == Storyboard.groupDetailsVC {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? GroupDetailsViewController {
            vc.sendedImage =  UIImage(named: "icon-checkbox")

        }
    }

}
```

//

```
class GroupDetailsViewController:UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var groupImageView: UIImageView!
  var sendedImage:UIImage!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.groupImageView = sendedImage

  }
}
```